# How can aborted builds be ignored concerning the Jenkins job status preview?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

For internal reasons, one of my jobs is able to run concurrently, but new builds abort themselves if another build is already running (disabling concurrency doesn't help, since I *don't* want new jobs to be scheduled for execution once the current build is done).

However, this behaviour is detrimental to the job status preview (the colored ball next to the job name when inside the job's parent folder). It often shows the status as "aborted", which is undesirable - I want to view the latest running build as the source of the job status.

I tried deleting aborted builds from within their own execution, but that's unfortunately neither trivial nor stable, and thus not suitable for this situation. I could probably get a workaround running that deletes them from a separate job, but that's not ideal either.

Anyway, I'm now hoping that I can just tell Jenkins to ignore "aborted" builds in the calculation of the job preview. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a setting or plugin that allows me to do this.

**Is this possible at all? Or do I need to find another way?**

Comment: ", I'm now hoping that I can just tell Jenkins to ignore "aborted" builds in the calculation of the job preview" => not possible

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/

I haven't used it myself but it supports blocking builds completely if a build is already running.